# Twitter tweet link not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I am trying to build a tweet pop up link.

My html code is below

```
<p class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1" id="custom-tweet-button"> 
<a class="twitter-share-button shareButton twitter popup" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=My Custom text"  data-text="My Custom text" data-count="none" data-url="https://www.google.com">
<img src="32399/images/social/tweet2.png"  alt="" />
</a> 
</p>
```

The javascript code is

```
  $('.popup').click(function(event) {
    var width  = 575,
        height = 400,
        left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
        top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
        url    = this.href,
        opts   = 'status=1' +
                 ',width='  + width  +
                 ',height=' + height +
                 ',top='    + top    +
                 ',left='   + left;

    window.open(url, 'twitter', opts);

    return false;
  });
```

The problem is when the popup happens, it just displays the text. **The URL from teh data-url is not getting displayed.** I need the URL to be displayed too in the tweet link.

I have created a sample jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yU9pP/1/

**As you can see that the data-url is not getting used** How to use that.?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the complete [twitter button](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button), adding the corresponding JS snippet solves the problem and activates the `data-url` use.

```js
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/URAtD/)

Comment: Hmm yeah. However adding that twitter snippet code also cause my custom image to dissapear. I was able to get this fixed by  adding after the text in the link

Answer (score 1):

I added the following in the href and it worked....Is that the way to do this?

```
http://twitter.com/share?text=My Text!&url=https://www.google.com
```